# How to run C++ library with OpenCV on the other computer (linux)?

Tags: c++, opencv, static-linking, ubuntu-11.04

I wrote a small project using C++, OpenCV 2.2 and g++ in Ubuntu 11.04. I need to make a library (.so would be better), but I want it to run on the other computer, without OpenCV installed. 

I've tried to build dynamic library using -shared and -fPIC flags for g++, and copied OpenCV .so libs to the working directory. Actually I need only core and feature2d, but actually it requested lot's of other libs, including highgui, which also has many dependencies. 

I tried static linking, using -Wl,-Bstatic flags, but also unsuccessfully. 
Did someone has the same problems? I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Static linking will not be really useful because highgui depends on several system libraries. If you don't need camera or video reading/writing then you can turn off most of dependencies. If this works for you then I can post a cmake command to build OpenCV without video support.

Comment: Yes, I don't need highgui in this project at all, but it is used by one of the OpenCV libriries. Thanks a lot, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to build OpenCV without dependencies from system libraries. To turn of all the dependencies for OpenCV 2.2 on Linux you can run cmake with following arguments:

```
cmake -DWITH_1394=OFF -DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DWITH_EIGEN2=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF -DWITH_GTK=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_PVAPI=OFF -DWITH_QT=OFF -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_UNICAP=OFF -DWITH_V4L=OFF -DWITH_XINE=OFF -DUSE_IPP=OFF -DOPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS=ON ..
```

But in this case you will not be able to use many of functions form highgui module:

- video reading and writing
- working with camera
- all functions working with GUI (like imshow)

Comment: It seems that `cv::imencode` and `cv::imdecode` are also in `highgui`.

Comment: indeed they are however they can work without system libraries for many formats